# python script with 1 or 3 positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a python script, it takes either 3 positional arguments (name, date, location, let's say) or 1 argument, which is a setup file which contains that information.

I know that I can use `argparse` and I can make the positional arguments optional with:

```
parser.add_argument('name_OR_setupFile')
parser.add_argument('date', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('location', nargs='?')
```

and then I can error-check, to make sure that the user didn't do anything stupid

The problem is that now the help message will be very confusing, because it's unclear what the 1st argument really is. I'd LIKE a way to do this as two different add_argument lines, somehow, but I'm not sure how.

I also know that I could use a `--setupFile` argument, and make the three optional... but I'd rather not do that as well, if I don't have to.

A third option is to use:

```
parser.add_argument('ARGS', nargs='+', help='ARGS is either of the form setupFile, or name date location')
```

and then error check later...

ETA for clarification:

I want to be able to call the script with either:

```
python foo.py setupFile
```

or

```
python foo.py name date location
```

I want the help text to be something like:

```
usage:
foo.py setupFile
foo.py name date location
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear on what you need? you can pass the help message in the add_argument call ?

Comment: FWIW, if I saw `usage: foo.py [setupFile] [name date location]`, my interpretation of the args format would be _completely_ different to what your describing.

Comment: @NPE: Good point. what format would be sensible do you think?

Comment: Also, by rejecting the `--setupFile` route, you're disregarding the standard way to do this sort of thing and creating unnecessary difficulties for yourself.

Comment: @NPE I would expect to see something like https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout where the SYNOPSIS section of the manual lists different forms and the short "-h" help indeed uses "usage: / or:"

Comment: also note that this program is run by non-programmers, in case that changes assumptions.

Comment: @JoshLee yes. I think that's what I want. I'll edit to that.

Comment: argparse is ideal for handling a lot of different command line options.  It's extremely powerful, but not a perfect fit for what you're doing.  Are you opposed to simply looking at `len(args)` and extracting your variables accordingly?

Comment: I'm not opposed. I'm just trying to generate help text sensibly.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily cite `git` as a good example, especially when non-programmers are concerned: https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/ :-) Seriously though, why not just look at `sys.argv` directly and simply use `print` for the help message?

Comment: If that's the best option, I'll do that. but I was hoping that argparse would help...  Actually, I can use argparse to do the parsing, but with add_help=False and generate my own help if I want to as well...

Comment: @BrianPostow If you manage to use argparse for flags but custom logic for the positional arguments, *and* use generated help for the flags and custom help for the usage line, that would make a fine answer to this question. :)

Comment: I'm currently looking into using multiple parser objects (for a different related problem) that MAY help here... or maybe just tack an extra : usage: blah line above the actual help message

Answer (score 3):

I think the clearest design using `argparse` is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g.add_argument('--setup','-s',metavar='FILE',help='your help')
g.add_argument('--name',nargs=3,metavar=('NAME','DATE','LOCATION'),hel
     ...: p='your help')
```

`parser.print_help()` produces:

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--setup FILE | --name NAME DATE LOCATION]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --setup FILE, -s FILE
                        your help
  --name NAME DATE LOCATION
                        your help
```

I've handled the `1 or 3` arguments requirement with mutually exclusive `optionals`.  And used `metavar` to add clarity to the arguments.  (As noted in another recent question, `metavar` does not work well with `positionals`.)

Another option is to use `subparsers`.  That still requires a key word like `setup` and `name`, only they are entered without the `--`.  And the help structure for subparsers is quite different.

Comment: Yeah, the working with multiple arguments is important. but Interesting, I didn't know about groups!

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure this is what you meant, but if I understand you correctly:

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    def dem_args(*args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            if os.path.isfile(args[0]):
                #go file
            else:
                #error regarding this being a bad filename or nonexistent file  
        elif len(args) == 3:
            #try to process / raise errors regarding name, date, location
        else:
            #error reg. wrong number of arguments, possible arguments are either this or that
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I'm currently doing. I'm putting this here for people to comment on, and in case it ends up being useful, for posterity.

I'm actually solving an additional problem here. The problem is actually a little bit more complicated than even I specified. Because there's actually 3 ways to run the program, and I want to be able to have a --help option for only give me the details for one type. So I want -h, -h 1 and -h 2 to all do different things.

My current code is:

```
import argparse

baseParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
baseParser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', help ='foo argument')
baseParser.add_argument('-h', '--help', nargs='?' , const = 'all')

parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents = [baseParser], add_help=False)
parser1.add_argument('name', help='name argument (type 1)')
parser1.add_argument('date', help='date argument')
parser1.add_argument('location', help='location argument')

setupParser=argparse.ArgumentParser(parents = [baseParser],add_help=False)
setupParser.add_argument('setup', help='setup file')

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents = [baseParser],add_help=False)
parser2.add_argument('name', help='name argument (type 2)')
parser2.add_argument('baa', help='sheep?')

realParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[baseParser], add_help=False)
realParser.add_argument('ARGS', nargs = '*', help = 'positional arguments')

args = realParser.parse_args()
if args.help:
    if args.help == 'all':
        print 'This product can be used in multiple ways:'
        print 'setup'
        setupParser.print_usage()
        print 'type1'
        parser1.print_usage()
        print'type2'
        parser2.print_usage()
        print 'use help [type] for more details'
    elif args.help=='setup':
        setupParser.print_help()
    elif args.help=='1':
        parser1.print_help()
    else:
        parser2.print_help()
    exit(0)
    #actually parse the args in args.ARGS, and work with that
```